# png in R: how many pixels for 300 ppi resolution?

Tags: r

In R, the png function allows length and width input arguments in pixel number rather than inches. How do I relate this value to PPI if I can't set length and width in inches? For example, the default png has 480x480 = 230400 pixels. How many square inches is the default image size, so that I can calculate ppi? I need to generate ppi=300 for publications, but to do this, I need to know how many square inches I am filling with X number of pixels.

Comment: png does allow you to set inches.  `png(.. units="in", res="300")`

Comment: I tried that option and get a "margins out of bounds" error. I found another stackoverflow thread about this problem, and the suggested correction was to set the length/width in pixels rather than inches. The trouble is, I don't know what the default square inches is for the pixel number.

Comment: square inches is a function of what you are outputting on

Comment: please see - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density